# Защита и доступ к папкам сайта. Как это сделать лучше?

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

Есть папка сайта в ней лежит `index.php` и `.htaccess`
Здесь же (в этой папке) подкаталоги: css, js, images.
Соответственно в css лежит файл `.css`.
В **js** лежат файлы `.js` и подкаталог php (в нем файлы `.php`).
В images лежат `.jpg` и `.png`
Как опытные сайтовладельцы защищают папки css, js, images у себя на компе?
И как защита происходит на хостинге?
Что прописывать в `.htaccess`?
Только пожалуйста подробней где что открыть и куда нажать))

Comment: Что значит защищают? И зачем защищать папки в которых хранятся файлы отдаваемые пользователю при просмотре страниц сайта?

Comment: @Visman вероятно речь идет о защите от изменения

Comment: @ЗвягинцевДенис, а вдруг речь про хотлинки? :)

Comment: @Visman зачем их защищать?

Comment: @ЗвягинцевДенис, запрещать. Чтобы чужие сайты не жрали ресурсы вашего сервера/ваш трафик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каждой папке куда хотите закрыть доступ пользователям создайте файл .htaccess и впишите в него строчку `Allow from all` эта строчка даст доступ к запрашиваемым файлам только для вашего приложения и запретит доступ обычным пользователям.

Comment: Большущее спасибо. Реально здесь получаю Вашу поддержку. У меня тут еще вопрос образовался "Как посмотреть откуда подгружаются мои изображения на мой сайт?"

Comment: В смысле откуда? Наверное от туда откуда приходит ссылка (www.site.ru/img/изображение.jpg например, значит из папки /img/)

Comment: @VitVlad, изображения подгружаются с каталога на сервере. Смотрите в инспекторе кода вашего сайта. Обычно это папка img.

Comment: да тут не все так просто. Кэш нервы поматывает. Ctrl+F5 не помогает, даже перегрузка компа. Я его отдельным вопросом вынес - если интересно (выше вопрос указан в ковычках как новый вопрос или тема).